# Why java call first NOT default constructor in this case?

Tags: java

Hi guys i need some help with this code to understand better constructors and methods. Why java first call the First constructor, NOT Default?:

```
public class Human {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Human() {
        this("Alex", 25);
        System.out.println("Default constructor called");
    }

    public Human(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        System.out.println("First constructor called");
    }

    public Human(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("Second constructor called");
    }

    public String info(){
        return name+" "+age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    } }
```

and

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Create object 1");
        Human person = new Human();
        System.out.println(person.info());
        System.out.println("Create object 2");
        Human person2 = new Human("Mike",55);
        System.out.println(person2.info());
    }
}
```

So output is:

```
Create object 1
First constructor called
Default constructor called    
Alex 25 
Create object 2 
First constructor called 
Mike 55
```

Comment: It **does** call the "default" constructor - how else do you explain `Default constructor called` in your output?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth OP is asking why the default constructor is called second

Comment: Okay, i understand, that i have "this" but why the output string "        System.out.println("Default constructor called");" is the second?

Comment: Because `this(...)` is first.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth is correct: The default constructor explicitly calls `this("Alex", 25)` *before* printing `"Default constructor called"`, so why are you confused about `"First constructor called"` being printed *before* `"Default constructor called"`?

Comment: Okay guys, i got it. I this case first calls the "First Constructor", after this, returns to run other code in public Human() . :)  thank you all

Comment: The class `Human` does not have a default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this statement :

```
Human person = new Human();
```

Will call the default constructor which is defined like here :

```
public Human() {
    this("Alex", 25);
    System.out.println("Default constructor called");
}
```

Now the first statement `this("Alex",25)` will call another constructor defined here :

```
public Human(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    System.out.println("First constructor called");
}
```

This other constructor sets some instance fields and then prints "First constructor called", when it finishes we get back to our default constructor at `this("Alex",25)` and on to the next statement which prints "Default constructor called".

In short : your printing succeeded calling the other constructor which made you think the other constructor was called first.

Comment: You answer was so nice, and then you messed it up on the last sentence. You cannot put the printing statement before `this("Alex",25);`. Not allowed!!

Answer (score 3):

This behaves exactly as it's supposed to, lets roll-up the function calls:

```
System.out.println("Create object 1");
Human person = new Human();
--this("Alex", 25);
----this.name = name;
----this.age = age;
----System.out.println("First constructor called");
--System.out.println("Default constructor called");
System.out.println(person.info());
System.out.println("Create object 2");
Human person2 = new Human("Mike",55);
--this.name = name;
--this.age = age;
--System.out.println("First constructor called");
System.out.println(person2.info());
```